# The Agentinstallation.sh needs to be run by user12. For user12 password is user12 how to pass this password to execute the below script

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible script, I am running ansible script from root user inside the ansible playbook I want to execute a script in another user(user12). Below is my ansibe playbook

```
---
- name: agent installation Script
  hosts: <hostname>
  gather_facts: False
  #Disabling gathering facts because playbook not getting executed on server
  tasks:

  - name: Copy the creating  script to Managed node
    copy:
     src: Createuser.sh
     dest: ~/
     mode: 0777
    become: true
    become_user: root

  - name: Copy the agent zip to Managed node
    copy:
     src:13.2.0.0.0.zip
     dest: ~/
     mode: 0777
    become: true
    become_user: root

  - name: Copy the agent response file to Managed node
    copy:
     src: agent.rsp
     dest: ~/
     mode: 0777
    become: true
    become_user: root

   - name: Execute the  script
    shell: sh ~/Createuser.sh
    become: true
    become_user: root

  - name: Execute the  installation script
    shell: sh ~/Agentinstallation.sh
    become: true
    become_user: user12
```

The Agentinstallation.sh needs to be run by user12. For user12 password is user12 how to pass this password to execute the above script.

Answer (score 0):

With option `-k`, this will ask for a connection password.

[From the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html):

```
-k, --ask-pass
ask for connection password

-K, --ask-become-pass
ask for privilege escalation password
```

Note the difference..

Comment: if i use -k it will ask password for root user not for user12. In the above script I am executing tasks with different users.